# How to re initiate Variable value in RobotFramework in mid of test case

Tags: robotframework

I have some variables defined in Resource file.

```
*** Variables *** 
${x}       SomeValue
# Derived String
${y}       SomeString_${x}
```

After using this in existing test case I modified `${x}`. After same am able to use `${x}` as modified variable but `${y}` remain unchanged. Do we have some way to re initiate `${y}` as per new `${x}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - not automatically; the value of `${y}` will remain as is, regardless that `${x}` changed.

The reason is the values in the Variables section are set once, on instantiating the suite. At that time the value of `${y}` is set to "SomeString_the-current-value-of-x", and that's it; e.g. it's not some kind of pointer to the present value of `${x}`, changing as `${x}` changes.

If you want to re-set the value of `y`, you can do it after you've changed `x`:

```
${y}=    Set Variable    SomeString_${x}
```